# Intellisense for LESS in Visual Studio 2017, Is there a way?

Tags: visual-studio, plug-in, less

I am beginning to use LESS for my CSS in my Visual Studio 2017 environment.

Thus far I have downloaded [LessCompile](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.LESSCompiler), which does a great job of automatically compiling my .less files into .css & .min.css files.

However, I would really like for intellisense similar to what is available in Visual Studio Code via [Less Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-less).

My team is very averse to switching to VS Code as we are a .Net shop, and they have been using Visual Studio for over a decade (Though I personally love both).

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how I could get intellisense in VS, if nothing else in order to stop it from constantly underlining my less specific sections as invalid syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I continued to search for options Visual Studio prompted me to install updates for my 2017 environment.

After doing so for all available options, and reopening Visual Studio, all of my syntax coloring and intellisense was working.

This would be my first recommendation if anyone faces similar issues in the future.

Note this does not provide intellisense for some newer features/functions still (ceil() as an example)